# Continue looping despite exception in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm writing some code to iterate through XML and I've come across a tricky problem. As I iterate, I'm unpacking values inside of the loop. When unpacking, I get an exception sometimes. I'm wondering how to continue looping despite the exception. I understand I could unpack the values inside the loop using `try` and `except` there, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this while leveraging the for loop unpacking syntax. The problem in the short example below is due to too many elements, but I'm looking to catch this and other potential exceptions.

Please see below for a similar example of the problem.

```
lst = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6,7), (8,9)]
try:
    for fst, snd in lst:
        print(fst, snd)
except:
    print("exception")
```

The output of this will be:

```
1 2
3 4
exception
```

I'm wondering how to handle it such that the code moves forward onto (8,9). Thanks!

Comment: What are you `except`ing? Move the try-except inside the loop?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ He's catching the exception from the fact that he's assigning a 3-tuple to 2 variables.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but it's kind of ugly:

```
lst = iter(lst) # so it wont restart

while True:
  try:
    for fst, snd in lst:
      # stuff
    break # if the loop was successful
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the "closest" answer to my question. Definitely ugly, though!

Answer (score 3):

In case tuple is sure to have minimum two items in it then, this seems to be simple.

```
for f,s,*r  in [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6,7), (8,9)]:
    print(f,s)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but what about a different exception that might be caused while unpacking? I'm looking for the syntax on catching any / all exceptions that may happen

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension that prevents the error in the first place:

```
for fst, snd in [x for x in lst where len(x) == 2]:
```

Comment: Thanks, but in practice this isn't always viable. For example, in my case I'm iterating through a large (potentially messy) file, and the condition to avoid the error might not always work or be about the same thing.

Comment: Then do the unpacking inside the loop.